# Axapta 2009 - Service reference enum

Tags: enums, axapta, dynamics-ax-2009

Is there any way to loop through all the enum values for a enum from a service reference in AX2009?

Comment: I'm not sure what you mean with service reference in this context, but have you tried one of the Google results, e.g. [Iterate through enum](http://dynamicsuser.net/forums/p/37069/191652.aspx)?

Comment: You should be able to find all possibilities in the WSDL. And thus in the object browser in visual studio consuming the service.

Comment: @Reinard: I know that that is possible, but I want to be able to do it in the code.

Comment: @FH-Inway: I have looked into it, but they require that you pass a type as the argument and I could not figure out how to find/set/pass the type for the enum from the service reference.